# Implement Level 1 cache with spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, jta

I want to implement a cache (i.e. cache result from DB query) that is specific to a transaction that is getting used. How can this be done?

1. Using JTA transactions with JDBC?
2. Using JTA transactions with JDBC without any external library?

e.g.

I have created a Function in the service.

```
@Transcational()
public void get(String id) {
   dao.get(id);
}
```

and I call create function is dao.

```
public void get(String id) {
   final String sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE id = ?";
    try {
      Object someObject;
       // TODO Here I want to check, If I have this item in cache specific to this transcation or not
      if (someObject == null) {
        someObject = template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {id}, someMapper);

      // TODO Here, I want to put the item in a cache that is specific to this transaction.

}
```

How can I implement a cache specific to transactions in this case? Without moving to JPA.

Comment: have you considered using spring cache? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial

Comment: Thanks, I have looked into this and I think this will work for the first part of my query i.e. "with help of any external library".

Comment: Just I have one question can spring cache be used to implement both level 1 cache and level 2 cache. i.e. Can I annotate methods in such a way that during the transaction it can get the Objects from the level 2 cache, if not in foud in transaction aware cache.

Comment: And any high-level idea, regrading part 2 of query i.e If I create manual cache how can I make that transaction aware without using any new framework or library?